# Disk space issue because of folder /var/lib/couchdb/database_design/mrview

Tags: couchdb-futon

Couchdb is installed on windows and we use futon to create the view.
Whenever i create a temporary view, a view file gets created in the above folder.
Since i am developing a business requirement which involves multiple creation of temporary view to arrive at the correct solution, this has resulted in multiple view files in above folder and lot of disk space issue.
Since i am not saving those views and it resulted in unnecessary creation of view file in above folder, how to get rid of these view files or take care of the situation and free the disk space.
Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the command. May be it can help someone else.
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5984//_view_cleanup

This command has to be run from command prompt.
Before running the above command change the drive in command prompt screen to something like D:\curl_7_50_0_openssl_nghttp2_x64